# php preg_match from html

Tags: php, preg-match

Hi I need to extract data from a web page, in this case I need to extract the number 278 from $sting.

```
$string = 'title="Metal:| &lt;table class=&quot;resourceTooltip&quot;&gt;
            &lt;tr&gt;
                &lt;th&gt;Disponible:&lt;/th&gt;
                &lt;td&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;&quot;&gt;278&lt';

$regex ='~title="Metal:| &lt;table class=&quot;resourceTooltip&quot;&gt;
            &lt;tr&gt;
                &lt;th&gt;Disponible:&lt;/th&gt;
                &lt;td&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;&quot;&gt;\s*\((.*?)\)\s*&lt~';
    preg_match($regex , $postResult, $match);
    print_r($match);
```

Above code outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => title="Metal: )
```

Ideally I'd like not to use url_decode function.
Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: `|` is a special character in regex...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something much simpler:

```
$regex = "/Disponible:\D+(\d+)/";
preg_match($regex,$string,$match);
var_dump($match[1]);
```

The power of regexes come from their flexibility.